# So I am trying regex but can't seem to get it right

Tags: regex

After doing some string magic these are the strings I want to use as regex

```
^api/school/$
^api/school/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/$
^api/internal/courses/$
^api/school/search/$
^api/school/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/rooms/$
^api/school/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/rooms/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/$
```

My Question is why aren't these strings matching to these respectively?

```
api/school/
api/school/123abc/
api/internal/courses/123ikl
api/school/search/school_name
api/school/school_name/rooms/
api/school/123abc/rooms/2/
```

Answer (score 2):

1st, 2nd and 6th are fine.
3rd, 4th end with $, means end of String, so extra word "123ikl" and "school_name" will result no match.
5th: `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` not match with **school_name** since there is no underscore.

Answer (score 1):

The first, second, and sixth are fine and will match. The third doesn't match because `$` matches the end of the string, and the third string you propose extends onward beyond `courses/`. Likewise for the fourth. The fifth will fail because `school_name` can't match `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` since there's no underscore in the character class.